# Prevent Advanced Excerpt from Being Called

Tags: excerpt

I have excerpts enabled for pages. In one of my page templates I want to prevent `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` from initiating the Advanced Excerpt Function. Basically, I have one page template where I want excerpts to function as they normally would. How do I go about accomplishing this while still being able to take advantage of the Plugin's functionality everywhere else?

Or - perhaps there is another plugin similar to Advanced Excerpt that is better suited to what I am trying to do...

thx!

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-excerpt/

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the plugins code in repo SVN trunk, you have only the option to add `the_advanced_excerpt()` manually in code. So simply don't add it, or did I miss something?